# How to show images in Django Template with out static?

Tags: python, django

I have an API which gives me a list of movies, and there images are in **HTTP** links like:

https://d2gx0xinochgze.cloudfront.net/5/public/public/system/posters/12/thumb/Tevar-Movie-Opening-Day-Box-Office-Collection-Report-1140x752_1482917123.jpg

So in django we use static file `{% static 'image.jpg' %}` to display images in templates, But how to display api images links in template?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What went wrong when you tried `<img src="https://d2gx0xinochgze.cloudfront.net/5/public/public/system/posters/12/thumb/Tevar-Movie-Opening-Day-Box-Office-Collection-Report-1140x752_1482917123.jpg">`?

Comment: @Selcuk what is the syntax of displaying API fetched images in django template?

Comment: They're URLs. You can just put them in an IMG tag.

Comment: Ok, how do you query that API? Post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{% static 'image.jpg' %}` doesn't magically make the image show up in the website, django renders the template with what its been given. Static means take a look at the statics folder, search for the given parameter as a file, and get the url for that given static asset.

In your particular case, you say you get the url of the images. You can easily add those urls to context, which is then gonna be a part of the rendering process.

For a function view it would roughly look like this.

```
def view(request, *a, **kw):
    template = loader.get_template('my_template.html')
    context = {'my_image': get_image_from_api()}
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

For a class based view it would roughly look like this.

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    def get_extra_context(self):
        _super_context = super().get_extra_context()
        context = {'my_image': get_image_from_api()}
        return {**_super_context, **context}
```

For both of these views, which are roughly the same; you now can use `{{my_image}}` inside the template to refer to the url. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

Fetch the images via python in views per say. Pass them through your context when rendering the page. Use django's template tags to put the URLs within  tags.